# Why residual equals to zero in linear regression?

Tags: data-analysis, linear-regression

I'm trying to solve a simple linear regression problem. considering that my line is "best fit", why the sum of the residuals always equals zero? what is the mathematical solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: That is because the sum of residuals is a half of the derivative of the sum of residual squares. When the derivative is zero, we will get a "least square" fit.

Comment: Actually, residuals are not equal to zero. The mean of estimated residuals is zero.